# Matlab not solving if statements

Tags: arrays, matlab, if-statement

I'm having a bit of trouble iterating through a few `if` statements more than eight times. The code seems to work fine for the first several comparisons, performs the arithmetic and return/saves the output row `'export_data'`. However, after that, it only returns the `else` condition and response. The variables beings assessed have 1500 rows each. I've added the code below and two photos showing the outputs. Any insight will be very much appreciated.

```
function [export_data] = WS_Zones(Forecast_WS, Observed_WS)
if (Forecast_WS > Observed_WS)
    WS_Zone_1 = Observed_WS.*1.24;
    WS_Zone_2 = Observed_WS.*1.28;
elseif (Forecast_WS < Observed_WS)
    WS_Zone_1 = Observed_WS.*0.76;
    WS_Zone_2 = Observed_WS.*0.72;
else
   WS_Zone_1 = Observed_WS;
   WS_Zone_2 = Observed_WS;
end
export_data=[Forecast_WS Observed_WS WS_Zone_1 WS_Zone_2];
filename = 'testdata.xlsx';
sheet = 1;
xlRange = 'A1';
xlswrite(filename,export_data,sheet,xlRange) 
end
```

- [Expected Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oB8mi.png)
- [Wrong Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HdOhG.png)

Comment: Matlab is behaving fine. I suggest you read the [if](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/if.html?requestedDomain=www.mathworks.com) documentation, specifically the sections "Compare Arrays" and "Test Arrays for Equality".

Comment: if `Forecast_WS` and `Observed_WS` aren't scalars, `if Forecast_WS > Observed_WS` will only depend on the comparison of the first elements in each.

Answer (score 2):

This statement:

```
if [1 2 3] > [1 1 1]
    disp('hello');
end
```

will never print "hello" even though `2` and `3` are both greater than `1`. This is because the `if` statement needs to evaluate to either scalar `true` or `false`. If a vector is used, than only the first element is used to determine if the statement is true or not (comparisons between other elements are ignored). You can use `any` and `all` if you want to apply conditions on all elements.

If `Forecast_WS` and `Observed_WS` aren't scalars then you need to wrap your `if` statement in a `for` loop, e.g.:

```
WS_Zone_1 = Observed_WS;
WS_Zone_2 = Observed_WS;
for i = 1:numel(Forecast_WS)
    if Forecast_WS(i) > Observed_WS(i)
        WS_Zone_1(i) = Observed_WS(i).*1.24;
        WS_Zone_2(i) = Observed_WS(i).*1.28;
    elseif Forecast_WS(i) < Observed_WS(i)
        WS_Zone_1(i) = Observed_WS(i).*0.76;
        WS_Zone_2(i) = Observed_WS(i).*0.72;
    end
end
```

or vectorize it using [logical indexing](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html#bq7egb6-1):

```
WS_Zone_1 = Observed_WS;
WS_Zone_2 = Observed_WS;
idx  = (Forecast_WS > Observed_WS);
WS_Zone_1(idx) = Observed_WS(idx).*1.24;
WS_Zone_2(idx) = Observed_WS(idx).*1.28;
idx  = (Forecast_WS < Observed_WS);
WS_Zone_1(idx) = Observed_WS(idx).*0.76;
WS_Zone_2(idx) = Observed_WS(idx).*0.72;
```